# What is the easiest way to determine whether `<input type="email"..` (for instance) is supported in current browser?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, validation

With HTML5, the following markup is just enough to get the browser handle input validation for one.

It will verify the input is matching an email address format as well as that it is actually provided:

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required/>
```

There is no need to hook on events, neither for the input box nor for the submit button, just fine.

I am looking for a way to decide whether browser already support this functionality or I should handle input validation myself.

I wonder if there is a way to get this straight forward, or shall I maintain a table of all possible brands-versions combinations and the supported flag.

Comment: The all-encompassing guide to detecting virtually anything: http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @deceze, the detection technique is described in [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#input-types) and the tool is [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.email) {
  // no native support for <input type="email"> :(
  // maybe build one yourself with Dojo or jQueryUI
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check the input type from modernizr library as mentioned by the 'Tzury' but here is the list of browsers and their versions which support the new html5 input elements.

Browser support for HTML5 Forms is growing, but limited. It appears that many browser vendors
besides Opera have not put significant effort into their new form controls yet. However, the WebKit browsers have recently increased support for forms, perhaps because of the introduction of the iPhone and its virtual keyboard display, as we will see shortly. More advanced features such as validation are just being introduced. Table 7-1 summarizes the current state of HTML5 Forms support today.

[image]

Checking for browser support is less useful in the context of the new HTML5 Forms, as they have been designed to degrade gracefully in older browsers. Largely, this means that it is safe for you to use the new elements today, because older browsers will fall back to simple text field displays for any input types that they do not understand.

For Reference you can check this book on Amazon [Apress Pro HTML5 Programming Sep 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430227907)

Comment: Where does the table come from?

Comment: why u want to know that? but i will tell you that i read it from an html book

Comment: the later version after IE 8.0 supports the new html 5 input types

Comment: When you don't supply a reference you are plagiarizing the original author. And since this is the web, you should supply a link. You might also be violating some copyright laws when you paste in a screenshot without consent from the author.

Comment: i dnt think so there is need to reference, anyhow you discouraging me in not a good manner

Comment: @Talha: No, he's right.  You should provide a link to a web page if that's where you got the image, or just link to the book on Amazon if you scanned it out of a physical book yourself.

Comment: Thanks, i have given the reference of book, you can check now.